# MongoDB: how to get specific elements from array?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have objects in the document that look's like: 
[image: my collections]

I want to get **only** the elements from the 'transactions' array that their inside field 'isMatched' == false

I tried:

```
db.myCollection.find(
{ "transactions.isMatched": false } ,
    { "transactions.isMatched": 1 
    })
```

But i got all the array elements: 
[image: results]

#### What is the appropriate query for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with aggregation. `$filter` helps to eliminate unwanted objects.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      company: 1,
      transaction: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$transaction",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$this.isMatched",
              false
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/32IvuS3nQfD)